# (Symfony 2.3) Doctrine Mapping column names

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.3

Is it possible to map column names using a .yml file with Symfony 2.3?

**The annotation method works, but not using YAML files.**

Here's what I'm doing:

```
    dateCreated:
        type: string
        name: date_created
        length: '100'
```

the line  `name: date_created` doesn't affect anything. The same with single/double quotes.

Am I missing something trivial here, or is it just not supported yet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `column:` insted of `name:`

```
dateCreated:
    type: string
    column: date_created
    length: 100
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/basic-mapping.html

Comment: I see, I somehow missed that. Thank you

Comment: documentation is litle bit confusing because it mainly relates to annotations

Comment: yeah, I didn't notice the YAML and XML tabs in those examples